# How to focus back on first popup?

Tags: html, modal-dialog, popup

So i have 3 page there are :
-Main Page
-File Input Image Page(1st Popup)
-Preview Image File(2nd Popup)

On the main page there is a popup using a modal. And in the popup page there is another popup to preview the image using modal too.

The problem is, if i close the second pop up. It will go back to the 1st popup page, but the scroll is focus on the main page. So if i scroll it, the main page that scrolled not the 1st popup

I want to make the scroll is for the 1st popup

Can i do that, or i should use another method to do it?

Sorry for the bad english.Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest removing the `C#` and `asp.net-mvc` tags and replace them with `html` and `javascript`. Also, ideally add an [mcve] (and maybe a jsfiddle, too).

Comment: Any library are you using for modal ?

Comment: In modal im using krajee file input, in the krajee file input there is a preview button(for the 2nd popup)